# How to implement dashboard widgets in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core

I've downloaded a dashboard template and creating a web application. I want to display a widget with values(no. of total books) from my SQL database(lms) table(books). I have the code for the widget. I want to know how to edit this and get value from my database.**I am newbie to ASP.Net core.** i don't have any code in demo.aspx.cs.

demo.aspx

```
     <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Librarian/librarian.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="demo.aspx.cs" Inherits="LibraryManagementSystem.Librarian.demo" %>
```

```
             <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card text-white bg-flat-color-1">
                        <div class="card-body pb-0">
                            <div class="dropdown float-right">
                                <button class="btn bg-transparent dropdown-toggle theme-toggle text-light" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu-content">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="mb-0">
                                <span class="count">10468</span>
                            </h4>
                            <p class="text-light">Members online</p>

                            <div class="chart-wrapper px-0" style="height:70px;" height="70"/>
                                <canvas id="widgetChart1"></canvas>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                  </asp:Content>
```

demo.aspx.cs

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   namespace LibraryManagementSystem.Librarian
   {
       public partial class demo : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

           }
       }
   }
```

I am currently having this. I need to get values from my database in place of 10468

[Demo.aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdlZw.png)

Comment: Read this link https://dottutorials.net/dynamic-user-defined-dashboards-asp-net-core-tutorial/ which may be helpful

Comment: This is somewhat not related to my question. Thanks for your help.